# Is it possible to do a BULK Insert using a parameter for the path instead of DynamicSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am new to Postgres development. We have a folder of JSON files that we want to Bulk Insert into a Postgres database.

Is it possible to write code that will perform Bulk Insert from a folder by taking a path in for each file , as a parameter.
As opposed to writing this in Dynamic SQL

Comment: You need to look into the Postgres [copy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-copy.html) command, and perhaps a reference [here](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/fast-csv-and-json-ingestion-in-postgresql-with-copy). Without more information not much more help can be given.  But v9.5, really, that reached eol-of-life 2 years ago. You should consider upgrading.